Pandas Loc selection to a list of NaN and Values
I want to select some points from a pandas data frame df under a certain condition and then add them to a plot using mplfinance.
Im using the mpf.make_addplot() function. This takes a list in the form of:
signal=[nan, nan, 7, nan, 6, 8, nan]

However selecting values from a pandas df gives a list like so:
df = pd.DataFrame({'column': [1, 2, 7, 0, 6, 8, -9]
pandaslist =  df.loc[ df.column > 5 ]
pandaslist = [7,6,8]

(Ofcourse the pandaslist has an index)
Is there a way to use pandas loc to get a list in form of the signal list?
Is there a way to make mpf to accept input in the style of the pandaslist?

What's condition? Is it possible it only selects non-null data? Please make a [mre]. For specifics, How to make good reproducible pandas examples.

@wjandrea I added a condition now

df.loc is used to access a group of rows and columns by label(s) or a boolean array (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) . You cannot convert values of the non matching condition to null on the fly.  For the mpf, you can have the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69712995/plotting-a-financial-graph-in-python-with-mplfinance-having-a-nan-column

.loc doesn't work like that.
Instead, you can use df.where() to select the values you want while nullifying the others.
df.where(df['column'] > 5)

   column
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     7.0
3     NaN
4     6.0
5     8.0
6     NaN

